# jQuery image fading and moving on load

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I need a help with a script but I'm not sure how to make it. I've done various animation scripts before but this is none like it.

So, basically I have a catalog that displays a bunch of images (with some text). I want the images to fly in fading in from top left (say 200 px from top left to top right).

I'm not sure if I can use the .effect('transfer') here. Any ideas?

EDIT: I have made this code and it works okaish. I just want to know how could I move it piece by piece? Like one .catalog per say 0.1 second interval

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".catalog").animate({
    marginLeft: '-=150px',
    marginTop: '-=150px'

            }, 0);
$(".catalog").animate({
    marginLeft: '+=150px',
    marginTop: '+=150px',
    opacity: '1'

            }, 800);


});
```

Comment: Do you have anything at all written so far?

Comment: Ah, yes. jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.catalog').animate({. I suppose it isn't much XD. As I said I don't usually do something unless I got an idea how to do it. It's the idea (or the way of doing it) that I need to grasp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out, I think this might answer your question

---

**HTML**

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="catalogContainer clear"><img src="http://www.plancraft.co.uk/Opening%20Page%20186.jpg" class="catalog" /><br /><span>boat</span></div>
        <div class="catalogContainer clear"><img src="http://www.speedcrete.co.uk/images/bc230.jpg" class="catalog" /><span>hoe</span></div>
        <div class="catalogContainer clear"><img src="http://www.plancraft.co.uk/Opening%20Page%20186.jpg" class="catalog" /><span>boat</span></div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container
{
    float: left;
    max-width: 80px;
}

.catalogContainer
{
    display: none;
    height: 90px;
    width: 80px;
}

.catalog
{
    height: 50px;
    width: 80px;
}

.clear
{
    clear: both;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $(".catalogContainer").each(function(i) 
    {
        $(this).delay((i++) * 500).animate({
            marginLeft: '-=150px',
            marginTop: '-=150px'
        }, 10).fadeTo(1000, 1);
    });

    $(".catalogContainer").each(function(i) 
    {
        $(this).delay((i++) * 500).animate({
            marginLeft: '+=150px',
            marginTop: '+=150px',
            opacity: '1'
        }, 800);
    });
});
```

Check out the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hb565z7h/4/) for a demo

Comment: Hey, KyleT. Yes, this is exactly what I want to do. But I tried applying it to my website and it doesn't work. It doesn't even move the images liek it did before. Seems like there isn't anything set (like there is no script). I checked, Google Chrome loads the script just fine (no errors). I will analyze your example a bit to see what I could be doing wrong.

Comment: @NikolaL. In my solution i removed the $(document).ready() function because JSFiddle does not need it. Im fairly confident that if you include it with your code then it will work. Ill update my solution with it now

Comment: No, no it's included. This is a Wordpress site and it has to have it no matter what. http://codepad.org/WGto0v4C By clicking on this link (or pasting it I guess) you can see my current code. Don't worry about the errors since it's php set (no javascript supported).

Comment: Strange, the code provided is valid as witnessed by the fiddle. Are you sure your HTML matches up with the classes included in the JQuery selectors? I added a few .catalogContainer, .container etc.

Comment: My html structure is like this. A <div class="catalog"> is the wrapper of the whole catalog. Inside there's <div class="catalog-row"> cells. Each cell represents one elment. I want that whole element to be animated. Inside catalog-row there's <div class="catalog-image"> which holds the image and there's h3 and <p> for title and description. The animation works but it doesn't move it like in your fiddle example. I have corrected the jquery to use "catalog" instead of "catalog-image" and it still animates all "catalog-rows" at the same time.

Comment: Please add the HTML you have currently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69308/discussion-between-kylet-and-nikola-l).

Comment: After discussion with KyleT I made it work. It was just about hitting the wrong html element. His solution works perfectly! Thanks KyleT!